# sphinx-versioning showing branches instead of version numbers

Tags: versioning, python-sphinx

I have finished the [tutorial](https://sphinxcontrib-versioning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) for `sphinx-versioning` completely. After running the following command, I obtained a new `index.html`.

```
sphinx-versioning build -r feature_branch docs docs/_build/html
open docs/_build/html/index.html
```

[image: versions]

However, I want to have version number such as `0.5.0` and `0.6.0` instead of the branches. How to stack the documentation with version numbers instead of the branches? I can't seem to find it in the official `sphinx-versioning` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In Pyramid, we create branches with the version number, e.g., `1.10-branch`. Alternatively you can use git to tag a version number, then go into the RTD Admin for your project, and under "Versions" activate it for publication.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I realized that sphinx-versioning does not recognize `tag`, instead it will only recognize `release`.

[image]

However, another problem with `sphinx-versioning` is that if you are using the `autodoc` extension, the documentation generated will be the same as your existing version across all branches and versions. The reason is that the `autodoc` will only generate the documentation with the package you are having on your computer now, it will not automatically download the old package and generate the older version of documentation for you. But there is a workaround for it.

### Complete solution (hacks)

Say you have two releases `v1.0` and `v2.0` on GitHub.
Then you do a `git checkout v1.0`, and build the html with `sphinx-versioning build <your source location> output1`.
Similarly, do `git checkout v2.0`, and build the html with `sphinx-versioning build <your source location> output2`.

Then you will have two output folders like this:

```
output1
├── index.html
├── master
├── v1.0
└── v2.0
```

```
output2
├── index.html
├── master
├── v1.0
└── v2.0
```

I am omitting other unimportant files here.

Now, we just need to delete that `v1.0` folder under `output2` and move the `v1.0` folder from `output1` to `output2`. Then you will have a perfectly working autodoc generated documentation together with a working versioning.

Of course, the drawback for this is that the build time would increase exponentially as you have more versions and you need to manually build so many versions. But still works as a quick fix. Maybe we can write a script to do this for us so that we do not need to build them manually?

### TL;DR

`sphinx-versioning` does not support versioning that well especially when you use `autodoc`. There are hacks to make it works, but it would be very slow and tedious.
If you want something convenient and don't mind having ads on your documentation, just follow Steve Piercy's suggestions and use the hosting service provided by RTD.